# WebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, webview

this is a re-post of a question i asked last week, got 2 answers that didn't work.

i followed a guide on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html and then created my own EditText field and a button. the code should explain it all, my problem is i keep getting a "HelloWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type" Error, any suggestions? thanks in advance!

```
    package com.text.text;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alt);
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okay);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Editable text = edittext.getText();
                String Tekst = text.toString();
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                WebView mWebView;
                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.loadUrl(Tekst);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
                class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;

                    }
        };
    }
});
}}
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem as well and the issue turned out to be the following missing packages hadn't been imported (you already have one in your source:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

This is in the example posted by CommonsWare, but is not included in the tutorial for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Move `HelloWebViewClient` from its current location to outside of `onCreate()` (but inside your `test` class). [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/WebKit/Browser3) demonstrating this.

Comment: If i go with your example, how do i go with 2 layout xml's ? i have a Alt.xml layout for the textbox and button, then the main layout with the webview

Comment: @user553642: You use a text editor and combine the two files into one. Or, you use the `<include>` directive in one to include the other.